# Rlibstree (getLongestCommonSubstring) generates redundant character

Tags: r, string

I am using the Rlibstree package version 0.3-2 with the function `getLongestCommonSubstring`

So I have character strings that only contain `0-9` and `>`; they look like this:

```
string A:
```

> 0113>0213>0212>0312>0411>0611>0711>0812>1012>1112>1212>1412>1313>1413>1412>1311>1211>1212>1012>1013>0912>0812>0712>0513>0612>0511>0410>0309>0209>0308>0207>0107>0007>0109>0010>0110>0010>0008>0007>0106>0105>0204>0304>0503>0603>0701>0801>0802>0803>0904>1003>1002>1001>1002>1103>1004>0904>0803>0802>0701>0702>0603>0503>0403>0303>0204>0105>0104>0203>0302>0401>0302>0203>0204>0104>0105>0106>0107>0307>0308>0409>0410>0311>0212>0113>0213>0113>0213

```
String B:
```

> 0113>0213>0212>0312>0411>0511>0410>0409>0308>0307>0207>0107>0108>0109>0010>0110>0010>0009>0107>0207>0307>0308>0309>0209>0309>0410>0411>0611>0711>0812>0912>1012>1112>1212>1412>1313>1412>1212>1112>1012>1013>0912>0812>0612>0613>0513>0612>0611>0511>0411>0312>0213>0113>0213>0113>0212>0311>0411>0312>0213>0212>0311>0312>0311>0411>0410>0409>0308>0307>0207>0107>0106>0105>0204>0304>0503>0604>0603>0602>0601>0701>0801>0802>0803>0804>0904>1004>1003>1002>1001>1002>1001>1003>1004>0904>0803>0802>0801>0701>0602>0604>0504>0404>0304>0104>0105>0107>0108>0109>0108>0107>0207>0308>0409>0410>0311>0212>0213

```
String C:
```

> 0113>0213>0113>0213>0113>0213>0212>0311>0411>0611>0812>0912>1012>1212>1312>1412>1413>1314>1313>1213>1413>1412>1411>1311>1212>1011>0911>0811>0712>0611>0411>0410>0409>0309>0209>0309>0408>0410>0510>0611>0712>0611>0511>0411>0311>0310>0409>0309>0307>0207>0108>0109>0110>0010>0109>0108>0107>0006>0106>0105>0204>0203>0303>0204>0203>0302>0401>0402>0401>0302>0203>0304>0404>0504>0503>0604>0705>0605>0705>0604>0505>0504>0603>0503>0403>0303>0203>0104>0105>0005>0107>0108>0109>0108>0107>0207>0107>0106>0104>0204>0304>0404>0504>0603>0604>0603>0503>0504>0603>0702>0701>0801>0802>0804>0904>1004>1003>1002>1001>1002>1003>1104>1205>1304>1303>1403>1404>1403>1304>1205>1104>0904>0804>0802>0801>0701>0602>0703>0604>0704>0602>0701>0601>0602>0603>0504>0404>0303>0203>0204>0105>0106>0107>0207>0308>0408>0409>0308>0309>0409>0410>0411>0511>0611>0812>0912>1012>1112>1012>0912>1013>1012>1112>1212>1312>1313>1213>1313>1312>1412>1313>1312>1413>1313>1213>1313>1312>1112>1012>0911>1011>1112>1312>1412>1312>1413>1313>1312>1212>1112>0911>0811>0711>0511>0411>0312>0212>0312>0411>0511>0611>0612>0413>0513>0612>0611>0411>0312>0212>0213>0212>0213>0113>0213>0113

I want my input string to compare with String A.
See example below:

If I compare A and B, no problem, found two longest common substring, happy!

```
getLongestCommonSubstring(c(A,B))
[1] "07>0106>0105>0204>0304>0503>060" "12>1012>1112>1212>1412>1313>141"
```

BUT, if I compare A and C, something happened, as you can see the result,
I got `\xc1` or `!` at the end, and these special character will change every time.

Execute First time:

```
getLongestCommonSubstring(c(A,C))
[1] "04>1003>1002>1001>1002>1\xc1" ">0603>0503>0403>0303>020!"
```

Execute Second time:

```
getLongestCommonSubstring(c(A,C))
[1] "04>1003>1002>1001>1002>11" ">0603>0503>0403>0303>020!"
```

Execute Third time:

```
getLongestCommonSubstring(c(A,C))
[1] "04>1003>1002>1001>1002>1\xc1" ">0603>0503>0403>0303>020\xc1"
```

With these special character, or escape character in the string, I cannot perform tasks like the `nchar()` function, these characters are redundant and annoying.

For me, the only difference between B and C is their length, their format is the same, I really cannot figure out why this happened.